# in python, is it possible to pass a parameter value which will behave like "missing" or "default"?

Tags: python

let's say I have a 3rd party function (where I don't control the code)

```
def f(a=1):
  ...
```

assuming I don't know the default value (or I don't want to rely on it not changing in future versions), is there a way to call the function with some value of a, which will be equivalent to calling `f()`

the use case is that the values should be passed from an external function, and I want to avoid boilerplate like:

```
if a is not None:
  return f(a)
else
  return f()
```

**EDIT**

clarification:

I want to do something like:

```
a = DEFAULT
```

for which `f(a)` will be equivalent to calling `f()`

Comment: [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Define a wrapper with a different default value?

Comment: You can create two functions or `args` using `*`.

Comment: If this 3rd party function is written as *def f(a=1)* then you **must** call it with some value if you want to override the default. You can't call it as though no parameters were given. Just calling *f()* obviously uses the default. If the 3rd party changes the function to operate with a different default then there's nothing you can do about that. If it helps... you can use inspect.signature to find out the parameter names and any default values

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use any thing, if you will supply the value default will be overriden.
example code:

```
def f(a=10):
    print(a)

f() //it will print 10 the default value
f(20) //will print 20, the supplied value
```

or if your case is to set default value in your code, then you can use partial function

```
from functools import partial
new_f = partial(f, 20)
new_f() // it will send the default value u set above and print 20
```